# Format datetime to YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss in moment.js

Tags: datetime, momentjs

I have a string in this format:

```
var dateTime = "06-17-2015 14:24:36"
```

I am using moment.js and I am trying to convert it into `YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss` -> `2015-06-17 14:24:36`.

I have tried this method

```
dateTime = moment( dateTime, 'MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss',true).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");
```

But getting dateTime as Invalid Date.

Comment: Shouldn't the variable dateTime be a string? Like so: `var dateTime = "06-17-2015 14:24:36`

Answer (score 321, accepted):

```js
const format1 = "YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"
const format2 = "YYYY-MM-DD"
var date1 = new Date("2020-06-24 22:57:36");
var date2 = new Date();

dateTime1 = moment(date1).format(format1);
dateTime2 = moment(date2).format(format2);

document.getElementById("demo1").innerHTML = dateTime1;
document.getElementById("demo2").innerHTML = dateTime2;
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p id="demo1"></p>
<p id="demo2"></p>

<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks for reply. I am getting date in MM-DD-YYYY HH:mm:ss format,and I have to convert it into YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss format

Comment: it should work now. You can try with the code I have updated my answer with.

Comment: moment("06-17-2015 14:24:36").format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");

Comment: I have date like this 2017-01-09T18:30:00.000Z and I need to convert it into YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss. I am trying this  dateTime = moment(2017-01-09T18:30:00.000Z).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"); But got time 0:00. Why?

Comment: I have the same problem as @Pooja, time is always 00:00 for me, even if I can debug and see that the moment variable has time data.

Comment: @Marcus use moment.utc() method instead of moment(). Like dateTime = moment.utc(2017-01-09T18:30:00.000Z).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss");

Comment: If your looking for the documentation reference:

https://momentjs.com/docs/#/displaying/format/

Comment: thanks a lot ! It was very helpful in typescript as well

Comment: @Pooja I spent hours looking for a solution to this until I see your comment - Thank you!

Answer (score 27):

Use different format or pattern to get the information from the date

```js
var myDate = new Date("2015-06-17 14:24:36");
console.log(moment(myDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss"));
console.log("Date: "+moment(myDate).format("YYYY-MM-DD"));
console.log("Year: "+moment(myDate).format("YYYY"));
console.log("Month: "+moment(myDate).format("MM"));
console.log("Month: "+moment(myDate).format("MMMM"));
console.log("Day: "+moment(myDate).format("DD"));
console.log("Day: "+moment(myDate).format("dddd"));
console.log("Time: "+moment(myDate).format("HH:mm")); // Time in24 hour format
console.log("Time: "+moment(myDate).format("hh:mm A"));
```

```html
<script src="https://momentjs.com/downloads/moment.js"></script>
```

For more info: https://momentjs.com/docs/#/parsing/string-format/

Answer (score 1):

const currentDate = moment(new Date()).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');
const Date = moment(dateTime).format('YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss');

Comment: this seems identical to older Answers ... what is new or different about your version?