# Convert date/time format using moment.js

Tags: javascript, reactjs, datetime, momentjs

I have a date/time in this format "07/04/2018 12:24 PM". I want to convert it to format to string like "July 24, 2018 12:24 PM" before submit it to server using moment.js.

```
  saveEditMobile = async()=> {
    await this.setDateTimebeforeSubmit().then(axios.put(host+"audience/"+this.state.CurrentEditMobile,this.state))
  }

  setDateTimebeforeSubmit = () => {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
    const prev_process_date = moment(this.state.process_date, 'MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A').format('MMMM DD, YYYY h:mm A')
    this.setState({
      process_date: prev_process_date,
    })
    resolve()
  })}
```

However, after I ran the above code. The data I sent to server was 2018-07-10T17:55:00.000Z. I don't know want happen to my code. Process_date value in the current state was July 24, 2018 12:24 PM. How do I resolve this?

Comment: Already someone solved this query[enter link description here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888197/format-datetime-to-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-in-moment-js)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`setState` is asynchronous, so you need to make sure the state has updated if you plan on using `this.state` directly after. You could pass `resolve` as the second argument to `setState` to resolve the promise when the state has updated.

You also want to give a function to `then`, not invoke the axios request straight away.

You can also use the `LLL` moment format to get the desired output.

```
saveEditMobile = async () => {
  await this.setDateTimebeforeSubmit().then(() => {
    axios.put(host + "audience/" + this.state.CurrentEditMobile, this.state);
  });
};

setDateTimebeforeSubmit = () => {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const prev_process_date = moment(
      this.state.process_date,
      "MM/DD/YYYY h:mm A"
    ).format("LLL");
    this.setState({ process_date: prev_process_date }, resolve);
  });
};
```

Answer (score 0):

```
moment('2016-03-12 13:00:00').format('LLL')

output :"March 13, 2016 2:00 PM"
```

for further information you can use given link : https://momentjs.com/guides/