# Moment js format from custom format string

Tags: javascript, momentjs

I have a string '20-08-2018' (dd-mm-yyyy). How can I format it to (YYYY-MM-DD) moment format. WhenI'm trying to format, I got an "Invalid date"

```
moment(value).format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Format datetime to YYYY-MM-DD HH:mm:ss in moment.js](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30888197/format-datetime-to-yyyy-mm-dd-hhmmss-in-moment-js)

Answer (score 17, accepted):

Your input value is ambiguous. You should specify the input format:

```
moment('20-08-2018', 'DD-MM-YYYY').format('YYYY-MM-DD')
```